# Debian Kernel upgrade - problems with module

Tags: linux, debian

I am trying to update my Debian Server (version 6.0.3 returned from `lsb_release`) from kernel 2.6.8 to 2.6.32, but it keeps saying, that my Network Driver is tg3 even though I have create a blacklist with tg3 in /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist
It should use e1000

How can I set it?

I do not have a possibility to come near the server in the nearest future, so I have to create as a script, which could then be run on boot or by cron, if I can not set it in a config-file

**EDIT** I figured out due `ethtool` and the bus, that the numbering of the 2 network interfaces was changed, when they were going to set up, but still I can't figure out, why the interface will not come up. I have created the same configuration for both interfaces in `/etc/network/interfaces`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I still got no answer for how to "rename" the network interfaces, but it worked creating the same configuration for both interfaces

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about your current Debian version, but more recent versions require blacklisting of modules in `/etc/modprobe.d/yourmodulename.conf` by adding a line like:

```
blacklist yourmodulename
```

The `.conf` extensions seem to be required now. I hope that's the issue, actually.

Comment: I tried with /etc/modprobe.d/tg3.conf; with the content `blacklist tg3`. But with no help